# Error EAGAIN en chat Laravel Vue y Pusher, en hosting compartido

Tags: vue.js, laravel-7, deployment, pusher

Tengo una aplicación Laravel 7 con un chat hecho con Vue, utilizo Pusher. En local para que funcione el feedback en tiempo real ejecuto npm run dev o npm run watch y todo va correcto. Al subirlo al hosting vinieron los problemas. Utilicé primero ssh, cloné el repo de GitHub, ejecuté `composer install` y `npm install`. La estructura de las carpetas es:

```
- CarpetaLaravel
- public_html
    - dominio.com
```

Dentro de dominio.com está todo el contenido de la carpeta *public* de *CarpetaLaravel*. Cambié las líneas correspondientes en el *index.php* como se indica en la guía que seguí:

```
require __DIR__.'/../../CarpetaLaravel/vendor/autoload.php';
$app = require_once __DIR__.'/../../CarpetaLaravel/bootstrap/app.php';
```

El AppServiceProvider.php:

```
   public function register()
   {
      $this->app->bind('path.public', function() {
        return base_path().'/../public_html/dominio.com';
    });
   }
```

En routes/web.php (por un error auth que salía en la consola del navegador):

```
Route::post('/broadcasting/auth', function () {
    return Auth::user();
});
```

En config/database.php (por un error de sintaxis de la query que salía en el archivo log):

```
'strict' => false,
```

He intentado ejecutar `npm run dev`, `npm run prod` o `npm run watch` y me sale el siguiente error en la consola ssh:

```
npm run watch

> watch
> npm run development -- --watch


> development
> cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js "--watch"

events.js:200
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: spawn node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js EAGAIN
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:264:19)
    at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:456:16)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:81:21)
Emitted 'error' event on ChildProcess instance at:
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:270:12)
    at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:456:16)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:81:21) {
  errno: 'EAGAIN',
  code: 'EAGAIN',
  syscall: 'spawn node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js',
  path: 'node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js',
  spawnargs: [
    '--progress',
    '--hide-modules',
    '--config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js',
    '--watch'
  ]
}
```

Y el problema es que las vistas se ven bien, los datos que muestra también, pero el feedback en tiempo real no, tengo que refrescar la página para ver el mensaje recibido.

Probé eliminando node_modules y volverlo a instalar, limpiando las cachés, eliminando todos los archivos y subiéndolos por ftp... creando nuevas app en Pusher y cambiando las claves en el .env...
¿Y algún consejo para hacer el deploy correctamente en producción?

Comment: [En laracast han hecho una pregunta similar](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/elixir/mix-stops-npm-install). Si la información de allí te fue útil, explica en una respuesta cómo pudiste resolver el problema.

Comment: Lo vi, y realicé lo mismo, ejecuto en local npm run dev y subo los archivos modificados al hosting. Pero el feedback en tiempo real sigue sin funcionar en el chat. Tengo que refrescar la página para poder ver los mensajes recibidos. Necesito que funcione el chat en tiempo real.
Gracias igualmente!

Comment: puedes revisar este hilo: npm install node-sass --nodedir=/usr/local :
https://github.com/laravel-mix/laravel-mix/issues/1314

Comment: Muchas gracias, lo miré y realicé todos los pasos y seguían saliendo errores.

Answer (score 1):

¡Bueno, lo resolví!

Revertí todos los cambios hechos desde que salieron los errores. Me aseguré de que en local funcionaba correctamente y en tiempo real. Limpié el servidor (eliminé la web) y con la ssh la cloné de nuevo del GitHub para dejarla tal cual estaba en local. Me aseguré de cambiar el index.php con las rutas a la CarpetaLaravel y no le puse el fragmento del register en el AppServiceProvider.php. No se si esto dará problemas luego en otra cosa, testearé bien por si acaso, pero en principio, el chat ya funciona en tiempo real.

Comment: ¡Bien! No olvides [aceptar](/help/accepted-answer) tu respuesta cuando transcurra el tiempo mínimo.